# How to add common header footer using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make common header footer using jQuery. I am using this function for that, but it's not loading the content from header.html, it's showing the error in console (see in image)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQQyU.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $("[data-load]").each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).data("load"), function(){
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

This is my full html page markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

hello shubham

<div data-load="header.html"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $("[data-load]").each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).data("load"), function(){
        });
    });
})
</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the serve the files from server, perhaps `localhost` in your case and not simply open html file in browser.

The error message is trying to say `file` protocol is not allowed for what you're trying to do.

It's better to setup local server. You can do that easily using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server).

If you don't have [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed, then install it first.

Answer (score 0):

you should use localserver you can do that by using node.js command prompt

```
first access your directory and execute the following command : 
http-server . -p 8000

then you can access using the url : http://127.0.0.1:8000
```